# passenger stucks on AppPreloader forking, 100 cpu usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have an user login action.
There are a lot of resources (rails models) loaded for the user in it.
If the user has plenty of records, then the login process stucks.
And **htop** shows, that Passenger AppPreloader tries to fork:
Passenger AppPreloader: 'porject_path' (forking...)
I also have limited resources 1 cpu core and 3 GiB memory.

https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T0G26F919-FM6TP56M9/image.png

I can't rewrite the code, because it is old and has no tests.
What could I do with passenger to fix this ?